# Passing parameters to stored procedure in OBIEE 12c rpd from OBIEE 12c dashboard

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper, dashboard, stored-functions, obiee

I am trying to create an OBIEE report using stored procedures.
I have created a function in SQL Developer which takes a parameter and returns refCursor as output.

I, then, set the following query as **default initialization string** in physical layer of rpd:
`Select * from table(pipelined_emp(HR_DATA.GETCURSORS(parameter)))`

**GETCURSORS(parameter)** is my function.

For now, in place of `parameter`, I am passing a constant value.
While, I wish to pass a value from the OBIEE dashboard, similar to a prompt, to this function in the physical layer of rpd.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Session variables in the RPD being written into by front-end request variables: https://gerardnico.com/wiki/dat/obiee/obis/request_variable

Comment: Mr. Berg, I have already created a Physical Table of _Table Type: Stored Proc_ using `Select * from table(pipelined_emp(HR_DATA.GETCURSORS(60)))` . 
From the link you shared, I'm still unable to figure out how to pass a parameter in place of 60 from dashboard prompt.

Comment: Select * from table(pipelined_emp(HR_DATA.GETCURSORS(VALUEOF(NQ_SESSION.YOURVARIABLENAMEGOESHERE)))

Comment: And where do I create this variable?

Comment: The session variable in the RPD. The request variable is set from the front-end via a prompt or the SET VARIABLE command.

Comment: Hello Mr. Agarwal, could you solve your problem? Now, I have a problem exactly like you had and couldn't find any solution. Please let me know about your consequence. Thanks

Comment: I found that where and why I was wrong. The problem was around session variables which I had defined. The reason was that I had used reserved name (to and from) for my variables. I hope this experience be useful for others like me.